# munal connection database CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

i need to connect for many databases
the primary connection in the database.php
and there is no problem with that

but the another connections must be in Model

i use this class

```
<?php
class user_model extends CI_Model {

        public function test()
        {
        $specific['hostname'] = "localhost";
        $specific['username'] = "root";
        $specific['password'] = "";
        $specific['database'] = "ci_forsyria";
        $specific['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
        $specific['dbprefix'] = "";
        $specific['pconnect'] = FALSE;
        $specific['db_debug'] = TRUE;
        $specific['cache_on'] = FALSE;
        $specific['cachedir'] = "";
        $specific['char_set'] = "utf8";
        $specific['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

        $this->load->database($specific);

        //get data using datamapper
        $o = new db_user();
        $array = array();
        $o->where($array)->get();
        echo $num_rows = $o->result_count();
        }
}
?>
```

but the connection is not work
it's still connect with the primary database

**Error Number: 1146
Table 'countries.ci_users' doesn't exist**

***Note: i don't wont to but the another connections in the database.php file because i have more than 100 connections***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reaction to your comment to Repox, you most certainly must be using it wrong. His last solution must work, I use it myself continuously. Can you show what "new db_user()" is for an object, you might use the general database?

**Note:** leave the closing tag here, it's a model:

> For files that contain only PHP code, the closing tag ("?>") is never
>   permitted. It is not required by PHP, and omitting it´ prevents the
>   accidental injection of trailing white space into the response.

Try this for an example, it should return 30 values from the countries table.

```
<?php
class user_model extends CI_Model {
    public function test()
    {
    $specific['hostname'] = "localhost";
    $specific['username'] = "root";
    $specific['password'] = "";
    $specific['database'] = "ci_forsyria";
    $specific['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $specific['dbprefix'] = "";
    $specific['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $specific['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $specific['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $specific['cachedir'] = "";
    $specific['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $specific['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

    $specific_db = $this->load->database($specific, TRUE);

    $example_query = $specific_db->query('SELECT * FROM countries LIMIT 0,30')->result();

    return var_dump($example_query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe CI would think that you already have a connection available and it doesn't use the parameters you specify.

Try closing the closing the default connection by typing `$this->db->close();` before connecting with the new config.

Otherwise, you should return a new instance of the database object with the new config as specified in the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html) by setting the second parameter to TRUE. You should be able to use the returned object:

```
$specific_db =  $this->load->database($specific, TRUE);
```

Comment: 'not working' is not easy to help you with. One of the two should give you some other response.

Comment: now it's working with EvdTempel code

but i want to use datamapper